# Is there a Linux equivalent of CPU-z?

Tags: linux, hardware

I need to inventory the hardware on some Linux clients I recently "inherited". In the past, on Windows, I've used the excellent CPU-z to generate the hardware inventory. Is there a Linux equivalent?

Comment: Would you mind editing your question and changing the subject to describe what CPU-z does?  The only way I caught this question was from the tags, so with a clearer title you may catch the attention of other Linux experts.  (Remember, many gurus might only be familiar with one platform.)

Comment: For those not aware of CPUz its a tool that is used on Windows to display detailed CPU, motherboard and memory information.
http://pat.marcourt.free.fr/cpu-z.JPG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you can use **CPU-G**, see the example
>   [here](http://goo.gl/0ozIC)

CPU-G is an application that shows useful information about your hardware. It collects and displays information about your CPU, RAM, Motherboard, some general information about your system and more

Comment: That I will definitely have to test later tonight.

Answer (score 7):

```
% dmidecode
% cat /proc/cpuinfo
% lspci -vvv
```

As root will all show you info about both CPU and memory, you might want to run `update-pciids` prior to some of those commands in download the newest version of the PCI ID list to ensure everything reports your hardware correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers about `/proc/cpuinfo`, `lspci`, `dmidecode` and other tools are helpful.  I would try to get away with them first if I could.

But for big jobs, HAL is the major mechanism to enumerate and identify hardware on Linux.  Strictly, speaking, HAL is an API accessible over the system DBus, but there are command-line tools to make HAL information available for human or script consumption.

To start out, try this:

```
$ lshal
```

The UDI is a namespace within HAL for all devices in your system.  Everything else is key/value pairs where the keys are in a hierarchy defined in the [HAL specification](http://people.freedesktop.org/~david/hal-spec/hal-spec.html)

I'm not familiar with CPU-z, but if you are interested in CPU information, search or grep for `info.category = 'processor'` which will give you a list of processors on the system, the manufacturer, whether they can throttle, etc.  In general, `info.category` is the basic grouping of devices (battery, AC adapter, disk, etc.)

Comment: You should post the last paragraph as separate question if you really want answers ;)

Comment: Yes, I am unsure whether to post it here or on Stack Overflow.  Maybe I'll start here.

Answer (score 2):

```
% cat /proc/cpuinfo
% dmidecode
```

Answer (score 2):

[x86info](http://www.codemonkey.org.uk/projects/x86info/) can decode CPU features and display them in human readable from.

Answer (score 2):

You can list all hardware using

```
lshw
```

or

```
lspci
```