# How can I get processor/RAM/disk specs from the Linux command Line?

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find out details about hardware on the Linux machine?](https://serverfault.com/questions/48642/how-to-find-out-details-about-hardware-on-the-linux-machine)

How can I get processor/RAM/disk specs from the Linux command Line?

Comment: Similar questions: http://serverfault.com/questions/48642/how-to-find-out-details-about-hardware-on-the-linux-machine http://serverfault.com/questions/3552/is-there-a-linux-equivalent-of-cpu-z http://serverfault.com/questions/107234/command-line-what-is-this-machine http://serverfault.com/questions/55834/determining-type-of-linux-machine http://serverfault.com/questions/77920/how-can-i-find-out-the-server-specs-in-unix http://serverfault.com/questions/5031/how-can-i-find-out-what-hard-disks-are-attached-to-a-linux-box and more

Answer (score 148):

CPU

> `$ cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Memory :

> `$ free`
>   `$ cat /proc/meminfo`

HDD:

> `$ df -h`
>   `$ sudo fdisk -l`
>   `$ hdparm -i /dev/device` (for example sda1, hda3...)

Comment: cat /proc/cpuinfo is brilliant, never knew about this. Thanks

Answer (score 35):

**lshw** command is also really useful to get a lot of information about all the hardware !

Comment: `sudo lshw | less`

Answer (score 10):

`sudo dmidecode` command will also give you more hardware info than you ever wanted.

Answer (score 8):

[hwinfo](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Hwinfo) would be one way to do it.